# Pullback of a Hamiltonian

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, hamiltonian-path

I understand that a Hamiltonian vector field $H$ creates a Hamiltonian flow $\phi_t$. Now, in order to prove that the Hamiltonian is conserved one uses the following 
 \begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^{*} H &=& \phi_t^* \mathcal{L}_{X_H} \\
        &=& \phi_t^* i_{X_H}dH \\
       &=& \phi_t^* i_{X_H}^2 \omega \\
       &=& 0\
\end{eqnarray*}
but I do not quite have clear what this $\phi_t^*$ is. It seems to be some kind of pullback of $H$. **But to what?** Also, **why is the first equality true?**

Finally, **I was wondering how if the fact that the Hamiltonian is conserved related to the fact that the symplectic volume is constant under symplectomorphisms**. These symplectomorphisms drive the the flow, that is different points in the integral curve are related via symplectic transformations. **So how is the Hamiltonian conversation related to the invariance of the symplectic volume (Liouville's theorem)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pullback of a function (thought of as a 0-form) is just pre-composition. That is, $\phi_t^*H = H \circ \phi_t$. So $\frac{d}{dt} \phi_t^*H = \frac{d}{dt}(H \circ \phi_t)$. But (pretty much by definition of how vector fields act on functions) this is equal to $vH$ where $v$ is tangent to the flow lines of $\phi_t$. By definition of $\phi_t$ as the flow of $X_H$, this means $v= X_H$, and so you have

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(H \circ \phi_t) = X_H(H) = dH \, (X_H) $$

But remember that the Hamiltonian vectors fields are characterized by $\omega(\cdot, X_H) = dH$. So you finally get

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(H \circ \phi_t) = dH(X_H) = \omega(X_H,X_H) = 0 $$

The last equality is just the skew-symmetry of $\omega$. This derivative being zero means $H$ is constant along the flow lines of $\phi_t$.

Comment: A question about convention: You state that "$\frac{d}{dt}(H\circ \phi)$..is equal to $vH$." Should that be $v(H)$, or is the identification of this with $vH$ conventional?

Comment: By $vH$ I mean $v(H)$, the derivation $v$ applied to the function $H$.